# javascript keep certain properties across objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to remove every attribute from objects in array except for some of them:

```
var listToKeep = ['name', 'school'];

var arrayOfObjects = [{id:'abc',name:'oh', school: 'a', sport: 'a'},
                      {id:'efg',name:'em', school: 'b', sport: 's'},
                      {id:'hij',name:'ge', school: 'c', sport: 'n'}]
```

I am trying with this, but this is only trying to remove one:

```
arrayOfObjects .forEach(function(v){ delete v.id});
```

the expected result will be:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [{name:'oh', school: 'a'},
                          {name:'em', school: 'b'},
                          {name:'ge', school: 'c'}]
```

i don't want to use `for loop`.

Comment: Instead of one attribute, you want to remove several of them. So you need another loop inside the one you already have. It can be a `for` loop, or it can be another `forEach`, it really doesn't matter which. To see which attributes to remove, get all the current attributes (`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(v)`), then subtract the ones you want to keep (using `Set` is the easiest), then iterate on the remaining ones. Or you can test each object against `listToKeep` (which should also be converted to `Set` for better performance) to see if you want to remove or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can map each item in your array to new one, created by reducing list of keys to keep:

```
const newArray = arrayOfObjects.map(obj => listToKeep.reduce((newObj, key) => {
  newObj[key] = obj[key]
  return newObj
}, {}))
```

If you want to mutate original objects and delete properties, you can use two forEach loops and delete operator:

```
arrayOfObjects.forEach(obj => listToKeep.forEach((key) => {
  delete obj[key]
}, {}))
```

If you can use lodash or similar library, you can pick properties of object, e.g.:

```
const newArray = arrayOfObjects.map(obj => _.pick(obj, listToKeep))
```

Comment: Note that this does not remove attributes from objects in `arrayOfOfbjects`, but constructs a new array with new bunch of objects.  Be sure you know if you want a destructive or non-destructive operation.

Comment: @Amadan that what I was saying and addressed in my answer

Comment: yeah new array is fine!@Amadan

Comment: lodash is not prefered

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I know. Just commenting here to note that this doesn't answer the question as asked ("remove attributes from objects"), but might still solve OP's problem if it a non-destructive solution is okay. (Not saying it's a bad answer, but it does need the disclaimer.)

Comment: @Amadan yes this totally violates what the desired output should be in terms of variable value. But if OP is fine then it all ends fine :)

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the keys of each JSON object in the `arrayOfObjects` array and then if the key is not found in the array `listToKeep` then remove that `key:value` from the object. And since you want to change the existing `arrayOfObjects` so you can follow this approach to use `delete` on the object property.

```js
var listToKeep = ['name', 'school'];

var arrayOfObjects = [{id:'abc',name:'oh', school: 'a', sport: 'a'},
                      {id:'efg',name:'em', school: 'b', sport: 's'},
                      {id:'hij',name:'ge', school: 'c', sport:'n'}];
arrayOfObjects.forEach((obj)=>{
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key)=>{
     if(listToKeep.indexOf(key) === -1){
       delete obj[key];
     }
  });
});
console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```